# Copy the first file of month

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a backup folder and I need to copy the first file of month from it for each month. The problem is that in each month the first files have different date (not 0101, 0102,0103 etc, but 0401, 0302, 0503 etc(ddmm)).

Is it possible in powershell to set a condition for the file name such as: if the file name contains in this place (month) the 01, then copy the file, which name contains in this place (day) a number that is as close as possible to 1?

File name type: filebackup02012019.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the file `ModifiedDate` look like on these files?  I'd normally sort by the File CreatedDate or ModifiedDate before I tried to parse the file name.

Comment: All your requirements are quite possible but unfortunately StackOverflow is not a free coding service. We can help you with your own code but will not write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the files by month

```
Get-ChildItem | Group-Object {$_.BaseName -replace '.*\d{2}(\d{2})\d{4}', '$1'}
```

Then sort each group by date in descending order and pick the first result

```
... | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group |
        Sort-Object {$_.BaseName -replace '.*(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})', '$3$2$1'} -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Comment: Was interested in what the best way would be to deal with this problem, looks very good.